# How to use final svm regression model to predict new values of the dataset

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-regression, libsvm

I understand svm_predict function can be used to estimate or predict test output, but the arguments passed are like this

```
svm_estimate = svmpredict(y, X, model);
```

where y is the output_label and X is the input_data (3 columns)

I wish to find new values using svm regression model for example like this`new_value= f(X);`
Is something like this possible to be used ? If so could any ofyou help me out finding the solution.

Your help is much appreciated
Thanking you all.

Comment: This has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902712/how-to-use-the-function-predict-of-svm-model-in-libsvm

Comment: @Vishal thanks for the reply, but however question still remains. as per the link you recommended, as in how to ignore 'y' ? doesnt that throw an error message ?.--> not sufficient input arguments for the function svm_predict, in such  a case there would be no output.

Comment: Did you try [1] in place of 'y' and see if that works?

Comment: Ok, I shall try it out

Comment: @Vishal I tried your approach the prediction failed terribly, when I tried to predict with output. The test ouput with ouput labels has good prediction, but when i given new input values within range of the trained inputs, i would expect a close estimate. But it was quite opposite. Do you know if we had any better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any random values for `testing_label_vector` (or `y` in your example). Just make sure that `testing_label_vector` is a vector of the same length as the number of rows in `testing_instance_matrix` (or `X` in your example). Also make sure that `testing_label_vector` is type double. Here is the MATLAB-specific README:

> `matlab> [predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model [,'libsvm_options']);`
>
> `matlab> [predicted_label] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model [,'libsvm_options']);`
>
> - `testing_label_vector:`
>     An m by 1 vector of prediction labels. If labels of test
>     data are unknown, simply use any random values. (type must be double)
> - `testing_instance_matrix:`
>     An m by n matrix of m testing instances with n features.
>     It can be dense or sparse. (type must be double)
> - `model`:
>     The output of svmtrain.
> - `libsvm_options`:
>     A string of testing options in the same format as that of LIBSVM.

Comment: @Girard as you suggested i have tried but my input training vector has 5 columns i.e. 5 set of features, of which later for model usage i would be willing to focus on only 3 features. Therefore i can predict my single output  as a function of 3 features  like Aout =  f(x,y,z), using the trained model. Any suggestions as to how this could be achieved ?

Comment: @SrikarBeechu The `svmtrain` and `svmpredict` functions need the same features. With `svmtrain`, you are producing a model that learns how to map all $n$ features to a set of labels. Then, with `svmpredict`, you are using that model to map a set of the same $n$ features to labels for a new set of examples. If you provide real data in the `testing_label_vector`, you will also get information about classification accuracy. If you provide random numbers in `testing_label_vector`, the reported accuracy will be meaningless.

Comment: @Girard then how can the model be tested upon new data, don't you think it would be an overhead carrying measurements always ? then how and where should we use this model? what would be the application of regression if it cannot predict data without output labels.
My point is when the model is trained with extensive dataset, then if new input is within the range of training inputs, shouldn't our trained model estimate the result ?

Comment: @SrikarBeechu I don't mean the same numbers, I mean the same features. For instance, you might train a gender classifier using information about height, weight, and age. Your training examples would include height, weight, and age features and gender labels. Your testing examples could be new data but would need to include height, weight, **and** age features. You couldn't give the model a new example that only includes height features and expect it to give a gender prediction.